# Detecting how a batch file was executed

Tags: windows, batch-file

Assuming Windows, is there a way I can detect from within a batch file if it was launched from an open command prompt or by double-clicking?  I'd like to add a pause to the end of the batch process if and only if it was double clicked, so that the window doesn't just disappear along with any useful output it may have produced.

Any clever ways to do this?  I'm looking for solutions I could rely on to work on a machine that was configured more or less with default settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just ran a quick test and noticed the following, which may help you:

- When run from an open command prompt, the %0 variable does not have double quotes around the path. If the script resides in the current directory, the path isn't even given, just the batch file name.
- When run from explorer, the %0 variable is always enclosed in double quotes and includes the full path to the batch file.

This script will not pause if run from the command console, but will if double-clicked in Explorer:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

set SCRIPT=%0
set DQUOTE="

@echo do something...

@echo %SCRIPT:~0,1% | findstr /l %DQUOTE% > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 set PAUSE_ON_CLOSE=1

:EXIT
if defined PAUSE_ON_CLOSE pause
```

EDIT:
There was also some weird behavior when running from Explorer that I can't explain. Originally, rather than

```
@echo %SCRIPT:~0,1% | findstr /l %DQUOTE% > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 set PAUSE_ON_CLOSE=1
```

I tried using just an `if`:

```
if %SCRIPT:0,1% == ^" set PAUSE_ON_CLOSE=1
```

This would work when running from an open command prompt, but when run from Explorer it would complain that the `if` statement wasn't correct.

Comment: Another option: %cmdcmdline% gives the exact command line used to start the current Cmd.exe. When launched from a command console, this var is "%SystemRoot%\system32.cmd.exe". When launched from explorer this var is cmd /c ""[d:\path\script.bat]" "

Comment: Personally, I would indeed go for the `%cmdcmdline%` approach, but be aware that both start commands can be overridden in the registry!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Patrick Cuff's final example almost worked, but you need to add one extra escape, '^', to make it work in all cases.  This works great for me:

```
set zero=%0
if [^%zero:~0,1%] == [^"] pause
```

However, if the name of the batch file contains a space, it'll be double quoted in either case, so this solution won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overlook the solution of having two batch files:
   abatfile.bat and abatfile-with-pause.bat
The second simply calling the first and adding a pause

Comment: But how to find which one to call? I think that brings us back to the original question?

Comment: Hi Learning. If they are running from the command line they run the one with out the pause (because the output will still be visible), and if they run by double clicking then they double click one the one with the pause so that they can see the results and then dismiss the window

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use :

```
rem if double clicked it will pause
for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ("%cmdcmdline%") do if /i "%%#" equ "/c" pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a parameter "automode" when I run my batch files from scripts.

```
set automode=%7
```

(Here automode is the seventh parameter given.)

Some code follows and when the file should pause, I do this:

```
if @%automode%==@ pause
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it is described here:
http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-10-advanced-tricks.html
There is little typo in the code mentioned in the link. Here is correct code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET interactive=0

ECHO %CMDCMDLINE% | FINDSTR /L /I %COMSPEC% >NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET interactive=1

ECHO do work

IF "%interactive%"==1 PAUSE
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, as written, if the script is started with "run as administrator".......... But adding the case-insenstive "/I" option to the FINDSTR command fixed this. I found that the COMSPEC had case differences.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a second batch file you could also pause if a certain parameter is not given (called via clicking).

This would mean only one batch file but having to specify a `-nopause` parameter or something like that when calling from the console.

Comment: This is about the best manual solution, but I am really hoping for an automatic one.  Perhaps branching on the current directory, which may be constant when double clicked.  Ideally something with minimal setup that will work everywhere without screwing with shortcuts.

Answer (score -1):

crazy idea: use tasklist and parse it's results.
I've wrote in a test batch file:

tasklist > test.out

and when I double-clicked it, there was an additional "cmd.exe" process just before the tasklist process, that wasn't there when the script was run from command line (but note that might not be enough if someone opens a command line shell and then double-click the batch file)

Answer (score -2):

Just add pause regardless of how it was opened? If it was opened from command prompt no harm done apart from a harmless pause. (Not a solution but just thinking whether a pause would be so harmful / annoying )

Comment: I think that would be pretty annoying, at least for me.  Surely there has to be some environment variable or state setup that exists in one place and not the other I could use to make the choice!